# Using Google Cloud AppEngine admin API to create request with Python?

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, request

I want to query Google's AppEngine Admin API via the Python library to list a few things on my Google Cloud account. Lets take list services as an example:

You should be able to query the API with a link like this normally:

> [https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/{my-project}/services/services](https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/%7Bmy-project%7D/services/services)

But with the library you have to use the async function documented in this way:
https://googleapis.dev/python/appengine/latest/appengine_admin_v1/services.html

```
async list_services(request: 
Optional[Union[google.cloud.appengine_admin_v1.types.appengine.ListServicesRequest, 
dict]] = None, *, retry: Union[google.api_core.retry.Retry, object] = <object object>, 
timeout: Optional[float] = None, metadata: Sequence[Tuple[str, str]] = ()) → 
google.cloud.appengine_admin_v1.services.services.pagers.ListServicesAsyncPager[source]
```

Without an example this is hard to follow.

I've tried running it in my code like this:

```
return await google.cloud.appengine_admin.ServicesAsyncClient.list_services(
    "https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/utility-destiny-325416/services/services"
)
```

But there seems to be missing parameters besides the url which makes it hard to gauge what's wrong - i get the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_client'

Answer (score 2):

A trick I usually follow is to go to the Github link for the library and look for tests. In your case, you should check out the [Github Library link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-appengine-admin/blob/main/tests/unit/gapic/appengine_admin_v1/test_services.py) for test services.

Also see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69964974/15211203) about cloud functions can help you figure out the url for services (I know they're different APIs but you might glean something from it)